# Where can I find detailed procedure for SWIG in Visual C++ of Win7?

Tags: python-2.7, visual-c++, linker-errors, swig

I've tried with swig site documents but it says "_example" module name is not found.
I've tried with slideshare http://www.slideshare.net/e8xu/swig-hello-world but it's saying some linker error like as follows:

> Error  36  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NotImplementedStruct   C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
>
> Error  26  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___PyObject_GetDictPtr   C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample

and I've included python library in Linker additional libraries.

Error   32  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___PyObject_New  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_BuildValue  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   50  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_InitModule4 C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   27  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyArg_ParseTuple   C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   52  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyArg_UnpackTuple  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   35  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyBool_FromLong    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   39  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyCapsule_GetPointer   C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   51  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyCapsule_Import   C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   19  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyCapsule_New  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyDict_New C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   21  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyDict_SetItem C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   47  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyDict_SetItemString   C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   38  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Clear    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   48  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Fetch    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   31  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Occurred C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Restore  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   36  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   25  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_WriteUnraisable  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   20  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_AttributeError   C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   49  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_IndexError   C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_IOError  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   28  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_MemoryError  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   23  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_OverflowError    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   41  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_RuntimeError C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   43  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_SyntaxError  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_SystemError  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   45  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_TypeError    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   30  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_ValueError   C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   13  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_ZeroDivisionError    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   17  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInstance_NewRaw  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   15  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_AsLong   C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_FromLong C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   37  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyLong_AsLong  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   46  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyLong_FromVoidPtr C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   44  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyModule_AddObject C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   29  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyModule_GetDict   C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_Call  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   24  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs   C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   34  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_Free  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_GenericGetAttr    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_Init  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   40  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_IsTrue    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   33  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_Malloc    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   42  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_ConcatAndDel  C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   26  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_Format    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromFormat    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromString    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyTuple_New    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   11  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyTuple_SetItem    C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample
Error   18  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyType_Ready   C:\Users\Pachagad\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sample\Sample\Sample_wrap.obj   Sample

Comment: Make sure that you are compiling for 32-bit if your python is 32-bit. I can recommend using `distutils` and compile everyting from within python, see e.g. http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn6. Remember to set `SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS100COMNTOOLS%` before executing `python.exe setup.py build_ext --inplace` or run the command from Visual Studio command prompt